# How to make axios get request dynamically in react.js which has start and limit params?

Tags: reactjs, dynamic, axios

url: `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos/?_start=0&_limit=5`

How can we make it dynamic? (?_start=0&_limit=5 part)

Answer (score 1):

you can use string interpolation:

```
const start = 3;
const limit = 7;

const url = `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos/?_start=${start}&_limit=${limit}`
```

and then use `url` where you need it

Comment: That is the same thing I guess. I was trying if we can use state for this. Any idea about that ?

Comment: please update the question. It's not clear for me what you want to achieve

Comment: Is there any other way of doing it without actually initializing start=3 and limit=7.